# What champions scale the best in League of Legends

Tags: league-of-legends

In League of Legends I know different champions have different strengths in the game. I want to know what champions, maybe top 20, scale the best. This means that they are weak early but are strong later in the game. Example: Kayle is a champion that at level 1 has melee attacks and does little damage, but at level 6, 11, and 16 she gets stronger like more attack speed, ranged attacks, and waves of damage. I want to know if other champions scale like this.

Comment: Do you want to know which champions scales with levels? Or by any means? I guess that the hyper carry archetype may be what are you looking for. A good portion of adc start weaker but became killing machines if they reach full build. But it's about the items, not the levels. There are some champions wich get special bonuses at certain levels ( other the normal abilities upgrade )

Comment: @Fredy31 It is possible to answer the question statistically as riot has win rate by game length stats.

Comment: @ChunYin yes please do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Level dependant gameplay : Gangplank, Illaoi, Kayle**

These three champions have a scaling mechanic tied to their level.

- As the OP wrote, Kayle AA get special effect on level 6 / 11 / 16 which changes greatly her power level.
- Illaoi tentacles spawn and hit quicker at lvl 7 and 13, which give her a good powerspike at those levels.
- Gangplank has the same kind of step up at 7 and 13 with his powder kegs loosing health much quicker, allowing some swift and powerful combos not possible earlier.

**Infinite scaling : Bard, Cho'Gath, Kindred, Nasus, Senna, Shyvana, Thresh, Veigar**

I won't detail all of them but each of them has an infinite scaling mechanic in their kit.

- Bard (meeps), Kindred (marks), Nasus (stacks), Senna (souls), Thresh (souls) and Veigar (evil power) can all gain damage nearly indefinitely
- Cho'Gath (R), Shyvana (passive), Thresh (souls) can all gain survivability nearly indefinitely

If further informations are needed, do not hesitate to visit the wiki to consult these champions abilities [here](https://leagueoflegends.fandom.com/wiki/League_of_Legends_Wiki)

**A lot of champions need their 6th level**

Kassadin is the best example in my mind. He's not too weak early but his R changes drastically his threat level. Same thing for Malzahar, Mordekaiser or Skarner.

**Honorable mention : Zeri**

With her ultimate ability, Zeri can gain infinite movement speed.
Check on the wiki or Youtube if needed.

**I won't get into build dependent scaling**

They are highly dependent on champion, matchups, skill, team comp. Just know that a full stuff ADC is a killing machine.

And I probably forgot some so do not hesitate to suggest edits.

Answer (score 2):

The answer will change every other patch. To find out the current meta for late game champions and for a more statistical approach to this question, you can refer to this graph on lolalytics (and some other stat sites).

Example: Rek'Sai is notorious for being a menace early and falling off after players start grouping up. It's well represented in her chart.
[image: reksai's win rate chart]

Similarly, Kassadin who's infamous for being a late game champion has his win rate climb up steadily throughout the game.
[image: Kassadin win rate chart]

League has an API for this which lolalytics is using to get it's data, you can probably write one on your own to compare it as well.